# Java object attribute not showing in API Json response with Spring Boot Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a java dto model class which has some attributes. When in the API Controller class I am trying to convert the java object to json with objectMapper.readValue(..) it is not converting one field (_atType) and that is why in response body I am not able to see @type json key data.

**Model / Dto class:**

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Schema(description = "Abc...")
public class SomeDto {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id = null;

    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String description = null;

    @JsonProperty("state")
    private TaskStateType state = null;

    @JsonProperty("@type")
    private String _atType = null;
    
    public CheckServiceQualification _atType(String _atType) {
        this._atType = _atType;
        return this;
    }
    
    public String getAtType() {
        return _atType;
    }

    public void setAtType(String _atType) {
        this._atType = _atType;
    }
    
    .... other getter setters for other attributes
}
```

**Response json coming as:**

```
{
    "id": "55",
    "description": "Query Service Qualification POST Illustration",
    "state": "accepted"
}
```

**Response json expected like below:**

```
{
    "id": "55",
    "description": "Query Service Qualification POST Illustration",
    "state": "accepted",
    "@type": "Type1"
}
```

**API Controller method :**

```
public ResponseEntity<SomeDto> createQualification(@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.DEFAULT, description = "The QueryServiceQualification to be created", required = true, schema = @Schema()) @Valid @RequestBody QueryServiceQualificationCreate body) {
        logger.info("Received create QueryServiceQualification request.");
        String responseJson = "{ \"id\": \"55\", \"description\": \"Query Service Qualification POST Illustration\", \"state\": \"accepted\", \"_atType\": \"Type1\"}";
        SomeDto someDto = null;
        try {
            someDto = objectMapper.readValue(responseJson, SomeDto.class);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(someDto);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            logger.error("Could not able to convert json string to object", e);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<SomeDto>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }
```

So though responseJson variable in the API Controller method (above one) has "_atType": "Type1" but still in API json response in Postman I am not able to see the attribute "@type": "Type1" . Pleas help.

Answer (score 0):

Within the example you provided, the field name is provided as "_atType" in json:

```
"_atType" : "Type1"
```

However, it is specified as "@type" on model object:

```
@JsonProperty("@type")
private String _atType = null;
```

You will need to have "@type" field in json data or remove this part on model object: @JsonProperty("@type")

Comment: If I pass "@Type" : "Type1" in the responseJson variable inside API Controller method, then 2 entries are coming in API response json, "@type": "Type1" and "atType": "Type1". So still it is not proper as duplicate entries coming but with different key.